# Programatically get the latest file in php

Tags: php, csv

What is the best way to get the latest created file in a specific directory.

Say I have a folder named: `csv_files that is located in C:`

```
// Now the content in my C://csv_files/:
-filesample_20140509-1399602430.csv
-sample_20140509-1399603954.csv
-sample_20140509-1399608552.csv
```

Now what I want is to get the latest of `sample_*` and based from the above content the latest is `sample_20140509-1399608552.csv`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the latest file in C:\file:

```
$files = glob('c:/file/*.*');
$files = array_combine($files, array_map('filectime', $files));
arsort($files);
echo key($files); // the filename
```